# Grails 2.4.4 + searchable:0.6.9 runtime issues

Tags: hibernate, grails, searchable, searchable-plugin

When trying to add the searchable:0.6.9 (or lesser ones) on a Grails 2.4.4 app I get an exception thrown by hibernate4, but this only happens when I add the "**static searchable = true**" to my domain class.

Considering that my BuildConfig.groovy looks like this:

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()

    mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
    mavenRepo "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
    mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone"

}

dependencies {

    compile "org.compass-project:compass:2.2.1"
    compile('org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:4.10.2',
              'org.apache.lucene:lucene-spellchecker:3.6.2')

    test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    compile "javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final"
    runtime "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.3.Final"
}

plugins {
    // plugins for the build system only
    build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

    // plugins for the compile step
    compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.8'
    compile ":asset-pipeline:1.9.9"

    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    runtime ":searchable:0.6.9"
}
```

I get this exception:

ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: org/hibernate/impl/SessionFactoryImpl
Message: org/hibernate/impl/SessionFactoryImpl
    Line | Method
->>   95 | injectLifecycle in org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.lifecycle.DefaultHibernateEntityLifecycleInjector 147 doStart in org.compass.gps.device.hibernate.HibernateGpsDevice

**Does someone know how to make things work please?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the plugins mentioned in the title of this post don't mix! The GG landscape is changing rapidly and Searchable 0.6.9 won't shake hands with Hibernate 4.

Solution? I am currently considering [ElasticSearch](http://grails.org/plugin/elasticsearch) instead - freshly maintained (as of yesterday in fact) and mixes well with the fresh plugins. Does it do what Searchable does, meaning, ending up eventually with a search field that can be used to retrieve and display records from my searchable domain classes and/or searchable properties within? Will find out and report.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the searchable plugin works with Hibernate 4, but you haven't declared a dependency on *any* version of Hibernate, which definitely won't work.

In my Grails 2.4.4 app, I use the searchable with the following version of the Hibernate plugin

```
plugins {
    runtime ':hibernate:3.6.10.18'
    // other plugins
}
```

Comment: You are right, but it is just that I removed the dependency "runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1"" by mistake before pasting. I edited my original post now to show the exact settings I am using to get that error.

I tried hibernate:3.6.10.18 of course but then my app won't even compile! I am using JDK8u25, and I tried this on both Windows 7 and the Mac OSX 10. I get this when running with the older hibernate:

Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: ...